# corona sdk error on line creation

Tags: lua, newline, coronasdk, null

I do not understand why I get the following error: 
Line: 107
Bad argument #1 to 'newLine' (number expected, got nil)
I am trying to create a line between two touched objects.

Here is my code:

```
function createstar()
    ie = ie - 300
    astar = display.newImage('ls.png', math.random( 1, 10) * 33, ie)
    astar:addEventListener( "touch", star)

    physics.addBody(astar)
    stars:insert(astar)

    sceneGroup:insert(stars)
end 

function update(e)
    if(stars ~= nil)then
        for i = 1, stars.numChildren do
            stars[i].y = stars[i].y + 3
        end
     end
end

function star:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        -- Insert touched star into array
        table.insert(touchedStarArray, self)

        -- Check if array holds 2 stars yet
        if table.getn(touchedStarArray) >= 2 then

           -- if it does then draw a line between the 2 stars
           line = display.newLine( touchedStarArray[1].x, touchedStarArray[1].y, touchedStarArray[2].x, touchedStarArray[1].y)

           -- and empty array
           touchedStarArray = {}
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance, all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from code you pasted that you have one table listener and it's not the same object as each star created.

The problem is in this line

```
table.insert(touchedStarArray, self)
```

There are to ways to solve it.

One, very simple would be to put into touchedStarArray event.target not self (self is table star, not star's objects you are createing in createstar function.

```
table.insert(touchedStarArray, event.target)
```

Other solution would be to put listener into star creation function

```
    function createstar()
    ie = ie - 300
    astar = display.newImage('ls.png', math.random( 1, 10) * 33, ie)
    astar:addEventListener( "touch", astar)

    function astar:touch( event )
        if event.phase == "began" then

            -- Insert touched star into array
            table.insert(touchedStarArray, self)

            -- Check if array holds 2 stars yet
            if table.getn(touchedStarArray) >= 2 then

               -- if it does then draw a line between the 2 stars
               line = display.newLine( touchedStarArray[1].x, touchedStarArray[1].y, touchedStarArray[2].x, touchedStarArray[1].y)

               -- and empty array
               touchedStarArray = {}
            end
        end
    end

    physics.addBody(astar)
    stars:insert(astar)

    sceneGroup:insert(stars)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Piotr and Rob!!

Answer (score 1):

I would put in some print statements and make sure that touchedStarArray[1] really has a .x attribute.

\